# error while referencing a class in my sass file

Tags: css, sass

so iv'e started learning sass and i'm now in a spot when i added a class to my html `(.circle)`
and my sass file is already linked to my css file.
when i typed .circle to my sass file and tried to give him a color i incountred in the next error: 
**This selector doesn't have any properties and will not be rendered.
      error styles.sass (Line 6: Properties are only allowed within rules, directives, mixin includes, or other properties.)**

my sass file is really simple by now as i try to play with it:

```
body
  background-color: cadetblue

.circle
color: red
```

as i said when reaching the .circle i get the error. any ideas?
i used the sass --watch command and i use ruby devkit 2.6.5-1
thanks for helping! im new so i try my best

Comment: SASS is finicky about indentation. If you're just starting to learn, I recommend giving SCSS a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the syntax is not correct. Try this instead (remark the indentation on color property):

```
body
  background-color: cadetblue

.circle
  color: red
```

More info about Sass syntax : https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax#the-indented-syntax